# Adobe Air App EXE on a USB Stick

Tags: windows, flash, actionscript-3, air

EDIT: As it turns out, the issues described here were caused by an outdated version of the Adobe Air runtime. The Air app I had written was compiled for Air 2, but the computers were running Air 1.5. Updating the computers to Air 2.7 (the current version at the time of writing) fixed the problem. Unfortunately, running a newer Air app in an older runtime generates a misleading error. Beware!

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm building an Air app for internal use at my company. I need to install the app to a USB data stick, so that the installed app may be quickly moved from one computer to another. This works just fine on Macs, with the .air generated .app program running just fine on whatever Mac it is moved to.

When I do this on Windows, however, it only works on the computer that performed the initial installation of the .air file. Moving the stick to a different computer and running the program .exe results in an error message: "The installation of this application is damaged.  Try reinstalling or contacting the publisher for assistance".

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there any way to run an AIR .exe on a USB data stick regardless of the computer that generated the EXE?

Just to be clear: I'm not looking to move the installer between computers, but the .exe that results from running the installer. I want to run the .air installer once, take the .exe result, put it on a data stick, and then run that .exe on any computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simple recipe to make a portable Adobe AIR app

Ingredients:

1. A whole ziplock of [Adobe AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html), recently harvested from Adobe's server farm.
2. One `.air` package, fresh.
3. Command-line to taste.

Steps:

1. Extract the `.air` package with a [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) blender.
2. In this folder bowl, whisk in the `bin/adl.exe` and `runtimes/air/win` from the SDK.
3. Take the `META-INF/AIR/application.xml` yolk and set aside.
4. Make sure to have `adl.exe`, `win/` and `application.xml` in the folder casserole.
5. Add a pinch of `adl -runtime win application.xml` and let it simmer.

[image: adobe air cooking]

Optional: if you want shortcut sauce, just take note of the folder's location in your filesystem kitchen and re-write the parameters above so they have full paths to the `win` runtime and `application.xml`.

Finally, most `.air` will come with a baker's dozen `.png`s in the `icons` directory. You can use an icon oven to grill these into a golden crispy `icon.ico` to be used in the shortcut sauce.

Bon appétit.

Answer (score 3):

Compile the app to a native exe: http://www.beautifycode.com/compile-air-to-native-dmg-or-exe-files-with-ant.  That should do the trick!

and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html

Update: for full stand alone operation look into shu-player, or http://dmartin.org/weblog/how-run-adobe-air-apps-windows-without-admin-rights

Comment: It looks like this just wraps the installer in a .exe (instead of a .air file). I'm looking to take the result of running the .air (or .exe/.dmg) installer, which on Windows produces a folder containing an .exe, .swf, and support files, and put all that on a USB stick. Basically, I want to install it once, to the USB stick, and then move that installation to any computer.

Comment: Ahh, then your looking for shu player, but their website is down at the momment...

Comment: Also, this looks like it might be an alternative if shu-player dosen't come back up for some reason: http://dmartin.org/weblog/how-run-adobe-air-apps-windows-without-admin-rights

Comment: That just might work. If you change your answer to this, I'll mark it as correct (once I test it, if it works). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy method I always use (and I have never met the cases it hadn't worked).

Compile ".air" package, install it on your computer. After that, copy the following files from the app folder (keeping the directory structure intact) and run on any Windows machine which has the AIR framework installed.

Minimum set of files to copy:

```
\META-INF\AIR\application.xml
YourApp.exe
YourApp.swf
```

Once again, the limitation - your app can only be run on Windows.

Comment: That worked perfectly. For some reason, installing the AIR app directly to the USB stick failed, but installing it to the computer and copying it over actually worked. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken. I tested it on other machines, and had the same problem as before. After further investigation, it turns out that I had come to an incorrect conclusion. My problem was actually caused by running an app compiled for Air 2 in an Air 1.5 runtime. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In AIR 3 (in Beta right now), you can package an app as a "captive runtime bundle." On Windows this produces a folder that includes your app and the runtime itself. You can run the app from this folder without installation. Of course, some features won't work without installation. For example, registering file types for your app requires registry entries on Windows, so you would need an installer for that (or a utility program that set the required registry values would work, too)